# how to read pivottable excel using c#?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am developing add-in for excel and trying to read pivot tables but found no access to pivot tables from the worksheet , strangely pivot table can be reached from non add-in projects , I will be grateful if any one give me some info or code.

Comment: "strangely pivot table can be reached from non add-in projects" -- I'm not sure what you mean here? The Excel object model is the same whether calling it from an in-process add-in or via out-of-process automation. Can you elaborate on the two environments that you are operating under and what kinds of issues you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've checked the Worksheet.PivotTables property?!